# Change event firing when initiating the time picker on inputs

Tags: jquery, timepicker

In my code, I append an input to a div that's rendered in the page like so:

```
$("#output-area").append("<input type='text' class='timepicker' /><input type='text class='timepicker' />
```

After the append, I initiate the timepicker like so:

```
$('.timepicker').timepicker({
     timeFormat: 'h:mm p',
     interval: 30,
     minTime: '12:00am',
     maxTime: '11:30pm',
     defaultTime: '9:00am',
     dynamic: false,
     dropdown: true,
     scrollbar: true,
     change: function(){
           console.log("triggered");
     }
});
```

Oddly enough, when I the time picker is created, the change event is triggered the moment they are added to the DOM. I thought the change event triggers only when the values of the input have *changed* vs *created.*

Comment: So what problem does this present?

Comment: It triggers a change event? So really what ever function is in there is triggered on creation (ex: if an ajax call is being made).

Comment: And that's not on change, that's on creation + on change, which really could mess up a bit of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without modifying the plugin itself you could initialize in a loop and set a flag for something like `isInit` within each instance so you don't react to the initial call:

```
$('.timepicker').each(function() {
  var isInit = true;
  $(this).timepicker({
    timeFormat: 'h:mm p',
     .....
    change: function() {
      if (!isInit) {
        console.log("triggered");
      }
      isInit = false
    }
  });
});
```

Perhaps there is another event you can use but there are numerous timepicker plugins around so not sure which you are using.

To me this seems like a bug in the plugin

Comment: Yeah it is. I'm going to have to pick another time picker. The plugin hasn't been updated in 3 years it seems.